# In DBSCAN, can the distance between a Noise Point and Border Point be less than Epsilon?

Tags: classification, clustering, algorithms, distance, dbscan

In DBSCAN:

- A core point is a point which has at least "MinPts" points inside its Epsilon radius.
- A border point is a point inside the Epsilon radius of a core point, but it has a number of points inside its own Epsilon radius inferior to "MinPts" so it isn't a core point.
- A noise point is a point which is neither a core point, nor a border point.

Given these definitions, I conclude that the distance between a Noise Point and Border Point can be less than Epsilon: a noise point could be a noise point because it is inside the Epsilon radius of a border point, but it doesn't have enough neighbors and at the same time it's not in the neighborhood of a core point.

Is this reasoning correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct.

I just gave an example check this image
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Waiting for more reply to confirm this, but as I thought that's correct.